# Inconsistent subheading between latex and chm output

Tags: latex, markdown, doxygen

In the pdf output heading that should be at a depth of says 1.1.1.1 appear at 1.1.2 instead. This is not the same on the chm which although doesn't have the numbering does have a tree structure that shows this.

Please see the attached following snippets. I am using the standard doxygen Doxyfile. With the line:

```
INPUT = ../src/Chapters
```

We are using different markdown files for different sections and then linking them together using the @subpage command.

The main problem is the difference between the pdf and chm. I do not know why this happened. I initial thought there might be a maximum depth to the headings but I tried creating new documents down to that the depth and that works fine.

I would be really grateful for any help, and I am happy to provide more information to help.

```
Folder structure:
build:
    Doxyfile (doxygen default)
    html
    latex
src:
    Chapters:
           01.Numbers:
                   first.md
                   second.md
                   third.md
                   fourth.md
           02.Introduction:
                   fith.md
                   sixth.md
                   Using.md
                   short.md
```

and basically each markdown file calls the next with the @subpage command eg:

```
# First {#first}

@subpage second
```

This happens to a depth of four. And works for the 01.Numbers chapter but not for the 02.Introduction chapter.

https://itascaconsulting-my.sharepoint.com/personal/philip_usher_itasca-image_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=04323b09ba9c04e50ba57e46cd94dc341&authkey=AblWOqwbn3hjNM6ClIeEr68&e=3dd44fd86d02432892138b73ddb5e82e

Comment: Can you specify the doxygen version and add a small example showing the problem to this question. You mention chm output, how does it look in HTML output ?

Comment: @albert I am using doxygen v 1.8.13. I have added a link which has a small version. The problem is I'm not sure where the problem start therefore I have to have at least four md files in a minimum working version. If you have any tips about how I can break this down and yet still keep the error I would be happy to hear it. The html output also works correctly it is just the pdf/latex output where the headings have the wrong numbering.

Comment: Please add the files to the isue not a link a link is not persistent.

Comment: Thanks @albert I have added some more description so that more information will be availble for posterity. If we manage to crack this I will also be happy to edit the question to make sure the answer will be useful for others.

Comment: I created the directory structure as indicated and the md files (last 2 in the directories without further reference andI also set RECURSIVE to YES). I don't see a problem.

Comment: Any extra files (e.g. a md file in 01.Numbers). When adding an extra level I do see a problem.

Comment: @albert You getting the same problem that is only visible in the pdf and not to the chm? I'm struggling to find exactly where the problem is. It does not seem to be reliably after a certain depth and it only happend to the pdf. Which suggests the problem is when doxygen tries to output latex. I looked at the latex solution and found it was missing using a \section rather than the \subsection command. But not sure why it would do that. (editing the latex source would mean a lot of manual editing and cause me problems in the long term)

Comment: I looked in the code and have to do some further investigations to see exactly where the problem comes from and what possible remedies are. Problem is related to the depth, currently, supported in doxygen for pdf.

Comment: @albert I found changing the name of the file (which I didnt think effected the tree structure). Fixed one of the problems. I had to make the name of the first page in the chapter come alphabetically before the others. I saw that the xml output was putting things in the wrong order. Its weird how this ony showed on the pdf not the chm though? Any thoughts or suggestions as to why? So we can get a longer term solution.

Comment: Good to hear, what was the new name you used?

Comment: Something to come alphabetically earlier. So I had it my link the second chapter was called short.md so i changed it to a_short.md. Now with the full projet I have prefixed the filename of the first page of each chapter with 01. I noticed this before that the pdf output relies on the alphabet. If you remove 01, 02 from the chapter folders, they then go alphabetical.